# SSRS Column Grouping Based on Row and Column

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've looked everywhere but found no luck and did some tinkering which didn't amount to much. I have a table that displays the following result set:

```
| Name | Value|
| Pat  | 1.6  |
| Pat  | 1.4  |
```

I have to group them in together by Row based on the first column (which is not a problem). Although I'm trying to make the report put the two numeric values in one cell in the Tablix.

This is what I need to do:

[image: screenshot]

---

And this is what I have achieved

[image: achieved]

I achieved the third one by grouping it by the first column of my result set as a Row group.

Any nudge to the right direction will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new tablix and add Name field in the Row Groups Pane, then delete `details` group.

[image]

In the Value cell use the below expression:

```
=join(LookupSet(
Fields!Name.Value,
Fields!Name.Value,
Fields!Value.Value,
"DataSetName"
),Environment.NewLine)
```

Replace DataSetName by the actual name of yours. You will get:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Expression to surround the second value with parenthesis.

```
=join(LookupSet(
Fields!Name.Value,
Fields!Name.Value,
Fields!Value.Value,
"DataSet4"
),Environment.NewLine & "(") & ")"
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Wow. That just blows my mind. thank you so much! What if I want to encase the second value inside a "( )"?

Comment: @mPatrick, Will be there only two rows always? What is the rule to determine if the second value must be surrounded by parenthesis?

Comment: It's always two rows, I'm guessing it's just a concatination of the string with the second value?

Comment: @mPatrick, I've updated the expression, it will work if there are two rows always.